# save UITABLE data in a array in matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have created a UItable with dropdown menu in column 3. i want to save the modified table data after modifications by the user. Please guide me how do i do this.
thanks

FOR ref the code i wrote is:

```
f = figure;
s=1;
myData = {s 'q1' 'choose'; ...
      s+1 'q2' 'choose';};
t = uitable('Parent', f,...
        'Position', [100 100 260 260],...
        'ColumnName',{'SLNO.' 'Queries' 'select answer'},... 
        'ColumnFormat',({[] [] {'Yes' 'No'}}),... 
        'ColumnEditable', true,...
        'Data', myData);
```

Comment: _When_ do you want to save it? On user editing / on the click of a suitable button / at a prescribed point in your code? Also, _where_ do you want to save it? In a variable / in a figure that can later be reloaded?

Comment: i want to save the data as soon the the user finish the selection. for example for question1 the user selects yes ,and for question 2 the user selects no. his selections has to be saved in a array preferably..

Answer (score 0):

To perform an action on user editing, use the [`'CellEditCallBack'`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uitable-properties.html) property of the [`uitable`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uitable.html) object. That property can contain a handle to a function or a string. In the latter case, the string will be evaluated when the user edits a cell. So, add the following line in the definition of `t`:

```
t = uitable('Parent', f,...
        'Position', [100 100 260 260],...
        'ColumnName',{'SLNO.' 'Queries' 'select answer'},... 
        'ColumnFormat',({[] [] {'Yes' 'No'}}),... 
        'ColumnEditable', true,...
        'Data', myData,...
        'CellEditCallBack','newData = get(gco,''Data'');'); % this is the new line
```

This will update the workspace variable `newData` when the user edits some cell in the `uitable`.

If you want a more complicated action to be executed when a cell is edited, you can define a script, say `myAction`, and set the `'CellEditCallBack'` property to `'myAction'`. Or define a function, say `myFunction`, and set the `'CellEditCallBack'` property to `@myFunction`. In this case the function is passed a `CellEditData` object containing event data; see the above links for details.

Comment: it is showing error. it says CellEditCallBack function doesnot exist

Comment: i am using R2017a..Probably that may be the reason c..Can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: i jus copy pasted again..it worked.. sorry!!..:) anyways thanks a lot :)